# What is the difference between a keyword and a clause in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

My understanding is that a clause is a means of filtering the data set to certain conditions. Therefore `WHERE` being a clause makes total sense to me.

But in some of the tutorials I've watched, I've seen `AND`/`OR` referred to as keywords. It seems to me that they would both be a clause.

Could anyone help me understand this better?

Comment: AND, OR and WHERE are all keywords :) it's whatever comes after WHERE is considered the clause (up to the next clause that is)

Comment: http://forums.devshed.com/mysql-help-4/clause-statements-keywords-460910.html

Comment: _a clause is a means of filtering the data_ is not correct. The `FROM` keyword begins a clause, as does the `WHERE` keyword you identified. I don't know if there is a formal definition for "clause", but to me it means a section or block within the statement.

Comment: A SQL statement consists of clauses, one of which is `where`.  Review the documentation for `SELECT` and pay attention to the use of the terminology:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189499.aspx.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Making it clear by an example

```
SELECT  col1
        ,col2
        ,col3
FROM yourTable1 AS t1
INNER JOIN yourTable2 AS t2 ON t1.Id = t2.Id
WHERE col1 = 'aaaa'
AND col2 = 'bbbb'
ORDER BY col1
```

This is a `SELECT` statement or query

`FROM yourTable1 AS t1 INNER JOIN yourTable2` ==> `FROM` clause

`ON t1.Id = t2.Id` ==> `ON` clause

`WHERE col1 = 'aaaa' AND col2 = 'bbbb'` ==> `WHERE` clause

`ORDER BY col1` ==> `ORDER BY` clause

`SELECT`, `FROM`, `WHERE`, `ON`, `AS`, `AND`, `ORDER BY` are all keywords

Answer (score 1):

The words keyword, clause, and statement are used as follows:

A keyword refers to an individual SQL element. For example, `SELECT` and `FROM` are keywords.

A clause is a part of a SQL statement.For example, `SELECT employee_id, last_name, ...` is a clause.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help [Reserved Keywords](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx):

> Microsoft SQL Server uses reserved keywords for defining,
>   manipulating, and accessing databases. Reserved keywords are part of
>   the grammar of the Transact-SQL language that is used by SQL Server to
>   parse and understand Transact-SQL statements and batches. Although it
>   is syntactically possible to use SQL Server reserved keywords as
>   identifiers and object names in Transact-SQL scripts, you can do this
>   only by using delimited identifiers.

`WHERE` and `AND` are both `Keywords` and `CLAUSES`.

Comment: One could say that a keyword may introduces a clause, e.g. the `WHERE` keyword begins the `WHERE` clause.  However, the `AND` keyword is an operator, not really a clause by itself.